# Android repeating alarm in exact time-Using iteratively setExact, how to stop?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact...
>   There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see... setExact(int, long, PendingIntent).

So if I need exact repeating alarm- need to use `setExact` - sets one time alarm. So I have:

```
public static void setAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + ALARM_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
}


public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(context, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarm.cancel(sender);
}
```

The order of calling is:

1. User enables alarm via Activity, so the activity calls `setAlarm(getApplicationContext())`.
2. The alarm causing some service to run in the background-This is the purpose of the alarm: to run this service in the background in exact interval of time.
3. Inside `onDestroy()` of the service I call `setAlarm(getApplicationContext())` and in such way I have the effect of repeating the alarm in exact time. So in the end I have repeats not every interval but interval + execution time of the service until `onDestroy` is called.
4. The user can from some activity to cancel the alarm via calling `cancelAlarm(getApplicationContext())`. In this way the repeating effect of the alarm canceled: The service will not be executed, and specifically the `onDestroy()` method with the call to set new alarm will not be executed, so the chain is ended.

UPDATE: Result of `adb shell dumpsys alarm` when should run is:

```
RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{... type 0 when ... code.dev}
      tag=*walarm*:code.dev/.MyService
      operation=PendingIntent{...: PendingIntentRecord{... code.dev startService}}
  ...:code.dev +17ms running, 3 wakeups:
      *walarm*:code.dev/.MyService
```

And after cancel:

```
...:code.dev +359ms running, 14 wakeups:
      *walarm*:code.dev/.MyService
```

**Problem:** The service keeps waking up periodically, which means the alarm not canceled.

Comment: have you tried planting log statements in these methods and observe the actual sequence of events?

Comment: Also, use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see whether your alarm is still scheduled or not.

Comment: @muratgu Yes the calling order is kept

Comment: @CommonsWare please see my edit

Comment: One thing that you should change anyway is how you set this up. To use a `_WAKEUP` alarm, you need to use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`, pointing to a `BroadcastReceiver`. Nowadays, typically that will be a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, pointing to the `IntentService` that does the actual work. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast) for an example of this. Beyond that, what does "keeps waking up periodically" mean? How are you determining this? What does the service's `onStartCommand()` return?

Comment: @CommonsWare does using WakefulBroadcastReceiver will light up the screen? the service should run totally in the background while the device is in the pocket... thanks for the help

Comment: "does using WakefulBroadcastReceiver will light up the screen?" -- no.